# How to change system icon to different color

Tags: themes, icons

I was browsing Ubuntu Icon theme on internet, then I found [Papirus Icon theme](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/07/how-to-install-papirus-icon-theme-ubuntu). From the screenshot, I can tell this icon look promising enough. So I decided to install it.

Indeed, the icon offered colorful, nice modern looking and elegant design. I think I've found a icon theme that I really like :)

Still, there are things that bother me much. It was some system icon that has the same color as the menu background color, and is therefore invisible.

User icon : If you hover the mouse to "Guest Session", the icon will be appear.

[image: User icon]

Volume icon : Same goes for volume icon

[image: Volume icon]

Battery icon : Invisible battery icon

[image: Battery icon]

My question is: **How do I change these icon's color to different color (black in this case) ?**

**UPDATE**
Firefox screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

This problem is already reported to the Papirus icon site. Here is the bug report https://github.com/PapirusDevelopmentTeam/papirus-icon-theme-gtk/issues/18

But the developers closed the bug report saying that coloring symbolic icons are not possible in Ubuntu. Quoting from [here](https://github.com/PapirusDevelopmentTeam/papirus-icon-theme-gtk/issues/18#issuecomment-238078995)

> icons on menu indicator it's ubuntu specific bug only, because unity not colorize symbolic icons. I can't change volume icon because this solution broken compatibility with other DE's and GTK themes.

**About Firefox icon changes**

When you change theme, icons will be changed. The icons in the firefox toolbar are provided by Arc theme, not by Papirus icon theme.

---

Papirus comes with two variant.

- **Papirus-GTK**, for light themes like Arc (which you're using)
- **Papirus-Dark-GTK**, to be used with dark themes like Arc-Dark

So, Switch the theme to Papirus-GTK theme. The problem will be solved.

Here is an image of the Same menu with Arc theme with Papirus-GTK icon.

[image: image of theme]

Comment: Thanks ! Using papirus-dark-gtk alongside arc-dark actually solve the icon problem :)

Comment: But it change most of the application color, for example firefox. How can I avoid that?

Comment: @Motiun firefox application color where?

Comment: i edit my question

Comment: @Motiun I have seen the update. What you want the icons to be like? When you change theme, icons will be changed. The icons in the toolbar are provided by Arc theme, not Papirus icon theme